# Lock access to error_log from url

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, wordpress, deny

I have a website on WordPress.

Versions:

- WordPress 3.3.1
- PHP 7.2.13
- Apache 2.4.37

My problem is that, `error_log` file is exposed to be viewed from url.

For example:

```
www.example.com/wp-content/themes/MyThemeName/error_log
```

Can you please help me with dealing this and restricting access to error_log ?!

Answer (score 3):

Best is to reconfigure your website to NOT store log files in a public directory in the first place.

Adding the following to your httpd.conf (or if you must, to a .htaccess file)  is one way to block access to specific files:

```
<Files "error_log">
  Require all denied 
</Files>
```

Comment: I tried this code into .htaccess and restarted server. url is still accessible and logs in it are visible.